# Convert UTC datetime to local datetime in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is my code :

```
t = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
df['Time'] = t.dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
df['Hour'] = t.dt.hour
df['ChatDate'] = t.dt.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')
df['ChatDate'] = df['ChatDate']
```

The 'Time' field in the dataframe is in UTC, how do I get in my local time (Asia/Kolkata) or any other local time?

Comment: This may help: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`DatetimeIndex.tz_localize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_localize.html)** and **[`DatetimeIndex.tz_convert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.tz_convert.html)**:

```
t.dt.tz_localize('utc').dt.tz_convert('Asia/Calcutta')
```

Comment: @d_kennetz Don't think the dt accecssor is neccesary. `t` from the OP question is already of type DatetimeIndex... as per `pd.to_datetime`

Comment: Ah I think you are correct, as it is already datetime aware! I'll drop the first comment, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @d_kennetz actually, I think you're right! I've updated my answer anyway

Comment: I think it is safe to say that having it doesn't hurt, because if it is alread DateTimeIndexed it won't cause an error, but if it is not, it will.